# React Native - Cant find variable: Symbol

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

## The Scenario

I am writing an React-Native-Web (RNW) app.  The basic design is a core application that takes a library of custom React-Native components as a node package.

The component library is also an RNW app as i use StoryBook to allow development in isolation.

## The Issue

When i install the component library from git using `npm i ...` into the core application and import it into the App.js in the src folder i get the following error...

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Symbol

This error is located at:
    in Styled(SimpleList) (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by NativeApp)
    in NativeApp
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

I have also tried to install [es6-symbol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-symbol) but this doesn't seem to have any affect.

[image]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you imported es6-symbol? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, i imported it into the App.js using import 'es6-symbol/implement';

FYI, it seems to only be an android issue, the solution works for ios

Answer (score 4):

you need to

> npm install es6-symbol --save

and then inside index.android.js & index.ios.js

> import 'es6-symbol/implement'

If its only causing problems in android you might want to add this in index.android.js

> import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
>
> import 'core-js/fn/symbol/iterator';
>
> import "core-js/es6/set";

[issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4676#issuecomment-340290485)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I have tried both with es6-symbol and core-js but neither solutions work :(

FYI, this only occurs in Android

Comment: i imported it into the index.android.js in the root, i also tried it in the index.android.js in to src directory, neither worked unfortunatly

Comment: @supra28 I have tried both but after adding it the new error is: "Cant find variable: WeakSet" any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @supra28 for the solution.  The only change i had to make was to add

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';

import 'core-js/fn/symbol/iterator';

import "core-js/es6/set";
```

to the app.js instead of the index.android.js.  This solution works for both ios and android

Answer (score 0):

import these in your root index.js file:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```